# How to boot to tftp grub via a USB drive

Tags: usb, grub, pxe

I have a PXE server setup for network booting systems via grub.  Unfortunately, I don't have control over the entire network's DHCP servers, so I can't network boot all systems.  I'd like to create a bootable USB thumb drive that can be pointed to the ip/server name of the TFTP server to load grub from it and work entirely over the network from that point on just like the network boot systems.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it but according to [this](http://wiki.osdev.org/GRUB#Load_your_kernel_over_network_.28TFTP.29) you could build a version of GRUB (with support for your network card) that has TFTP support.

It looks like you can either create a config file that tells GRUB to TFTP from a specific IP address (without having to do DHCP first) or type those commands in manually at the GRUB command prompt.

Comment: What I'm after is getting the entire menu and bootloader from the tftp server, so I think the process I actually need is to chainload pxelinux (pulled down through tftp) from syslinux (found on the USB drive).  Your option seems to be to just download a single kernel.

Comment: Well you could TFTP whatever you want, whether it's another bootloader or whatever.  I didn't know syslinux could tftp in a bootloader though.